# Outlook 2013 meeting invitation to required attendees

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

How do the attendees know if they are required or optional when I send the invitation in Outlook 2013?  I am asking them to R.S.V.P. if they are required but, they do not see that status in the invitaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2013 displays optional and required attendees like this:

[image]